# Small shift when transforming from GIS to netlogo coordinates

Tags: gis, netlogo

When storing turtle coordinates as GIS coordinates, and then loading them into NetLogo  by converting them back to NetLogo coordinates, there is a slight shift in position.

This is the code I use to store NetLogo to GIS coordinates:

```
let env gis:envelope-of agentToStore
file-open "agentLocations.csv"
file-print (word first env "," last env)
file-close
```

And this is the code I use to convert GIS coordinates back to NetLogo coordinates (here x and y are coordinates read from the file):

```
 let envelope gis:world-envelope
 let xscale (max-pxcor - min-pxcor) / (item 1 envelope - item 0 envelope)
 let yscale (max-pycor - min-pycor) / (item 3 envelope - item 2 envelope)
 if x >= item 0 envelope and x <= item 1 envelope
   and y >= item 2 envelope and y <= item 3 envelope[
     let netlogo-x (x - item 0 envelope) * xscale  + min-pxcor
     let netlogo-y (y - item 2 envelope) * yscale + min-pycor
     ask patch (ceiling netlogo-x) (floor netlogo-y) [sprout 1]
 ]
```

Without 'ceiling' and 'floor', the loaded agent is always shifted by a cell in NetLogo. However even with ceiling and floor, there is still a small shift by in GIS space for some agents, which affects my output. Is there a better way of doing this?